# How to get updated json file for new form inputs using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Can I know that how to get updated json file for the newly entered form input fields. As of now, I can able to save my form input fields into my json file, but if I enter any new input value then if I hit my Save button, then this newly entered values are not storing into my json file(I can still see my old key/values). Please let me know where I'm doing wrong and how to do this ?

**html:**

```
<form id="imagesId">
    <input type="hidden" value="/images/Image1.png" name="Image1">
    <input type="hidden" value="/images/Image2.png"  name="Image2" >
    <input type="hidden" value="/images/Image3.png" name="Image3"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="/images/Image4.png" name="Image4">
    <input type="hidden" value="/images/Image5.png" name="Image5">

    <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Save">
</form>
```

**json:**

```
[{"name":"Image1","value":"/images/Image1.png"},{"name":"Image2","value":"/images/Image2.png"},{"name":"Image3","value":"/images/Image3.png"},{"name":"Image4","value":"/images/Image4.png"},{"name":"Image5","value":"/images/Image5.png"}]
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#submitButton").on('click', function(e) {
var jsonToSave = $("#imagesId").serializeArray();
var jsonData = JSON.stringify( jsonToSave );
    var $downloadAnchor = $("<a/>", {
        href: 'data:text/json;charset=UTF-8,' + jsonData,
        download: "Image.json"
    });
$downloadAnchor.text("Click here to download JSON");
$("#imagesId").append($downloadAnchor);
e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that `$downloadAnchor` holds a reference to a DOM element (a jQuery object = a DOM element wrapped in `$()`). When you append that element to the DOM, `$downloadAnchor` still refers to that same object. It doesn't magically duplicate it when you want to insert it again into the DOM, unless you `.clone()` it.

What you need do is to check if that anchor (thru it's ID/class) is already in the DOM, if yes, just update it's `href` with the new data as below.

```
$("#submitButton").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $("#imagesId");
    var jsonToSave = $form.serializeArray();
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonToSave);
    var $downloadLink = $("#download");

    if ( $downloadLink.length ) {
        $downloadLink.attr({
            'href': 'data:text/json;charset=UTF-8,' + jsonData
        });
    } else {
        $form.append(
            $("<a/>", {
                'href': 'data:text/json;charset=UTF-8,' + jsonData,
                'download': "Image.json",
                'id': 'download',
                'text': "Click here to download JSON"
            })
        );
    }
});
```

[**A demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ahu9vwd/) for the above.

**Edit:** To be able to append each file uploaded as an input (with a unique name + value of the uploaded file) to the form, you need to do 2 things.

1. Bind a `change` handler to the file input, if a file is uploaded (meaning, not just a click and cancel on the file upload dialog), append it to the form as an input with the file as the value (after whatever find/replace you want to do).
2. The `click` handler on the `$("#submitButton")` would only take in all the inputs, serialize them and then create/modify the download anchor link as in my first code attempt.

Here is a demo for the above (the edit part).

```
var $form = $("#imagesId"); //The form
var len = $form.find('input[type="hidden"]').length; //Number of files in the form

$form.on("change", ":file", function() {
    var file = $(this).val() || false;
    if (file) {
        //Do your replace etc. here
        //.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
        len++;
        $form.append('<input type="hidden" value="' +file+ '"  name="image' +len+ '" />');
    }
});

$("#submitButton").on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var jsonToSave = $form.serializeArray();
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonToSave, null, 4);
    var $downloadLink = $("#download");
    alert (jsonData);
    //Other code goes here such as create anchor, append/modify etc.
});
```

[**Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/ce5uaub3/2/) to the demo for the edits above.

Comment: I have created the fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/ce5uaub3/1/ . Please check it once and let me know for anything.

Comment: @Ishettyl, Hat's off !! Thanks a lot for your help !! It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `push` like this

```
oldJson.push(newJSon);
```

Comment: Hi amoeba, Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain in in code how to include it, as I'm not getting the values, getting my oldjsonfile.push is not a function error.